# Since when do we have UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, propertychanged, updatesourcetrigger

I'm developing in Silverlight 4 and in time I got used to having two choices for the UpdateSourceTrigger property of bindings: Default and Explicit. But today I found out I can also choose "PropertyChanged", which is very, very welcome but... unexpected. In the properties of my project I can still see "Silverlight 4" but somehow I get to successfully use a Silverlight 5 feature... Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: I guess you have installed Silverlight 5 developer tools.

Comment: ... I guess that occurred during some Windows update (grr!) So now people with the Silverlight 4 plugin won't be able to use my application... Great!
Thanks for the reply, anyway...

Comment: You can set requirement to silverlight version. See more info http://forums.silverlight.net/t/77989.aspx/1

Comment: I had to change the required version to 5.1.10411.0 because my application suddenly won't work with version 4 plugin anymore...